# How to calculate element width with different text lengths

Tags: html, css

I mean if I have this:

```
<ul>
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

for example the layout width is 900px, and those li tags have a width of 300px each by now, but what if I change the language of the site, the text length may change and the width are getting bigger or lesser, this is when it is automatic width, if I set the fixed width to the li tags, the text length may be bigger than the width I set, so how to resolve this puzzle?

I need to make the sum width of all li tags == layout width

Comment: Are you going to try to float the `<li>` elements onto a single line, for example, a navigation bar?  Or, the `<li>` elements going to form three columns on a page and contain paragraphs of text? Or, will the `<li>`'s stack vertically above each other (normal flow)?

Comment: yes i am floating them into a line, and i need to make the width of all those elements == layout width, and i don't know how to set the width right in this situation

Comment: You have GOT to say this in your question, otherwise we can't help you.  Also, does the `<li>`'s have to be all the same width or can they vary in width, and if so, is there a max width constraint? and what about the height?

Comment: yes the layout is for example 900px, the width of each menu element may differ, thats the problem, if they were equal i didn't ask this question

Comment: so looks like there are no solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) css property.

Answer (score 0):

If your `<li></li>` items have a width of 300px and your page has a width of 900px, then regardless of what the content is, their width shouldn't exceed whats in your CSS.

What is the actually Styling for these in CSS?

You may want  [to take a look at overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) css property. This may help with understanding what some limitations' affects can have.

Comment: If i set the fixed width to all the li tags, then in each of these li, may have a different text sizes, do i have to set each element width explicitly?, i wanted to make it automatically

Comment: by now I am setting padding to add width to the elements without limitating them, but its not the best way

Comment: No you're right, that's not the best way. What other styling options have you selected for `<li>` ?

Comment: try taking a look at the overflow link I suggested. Reading that should give you quite a good idea as to what might be going wrong with it.

Comment: i readed that, but I can't understand how to use it...can you give me a little example?